# why is visits 0 in some ga records?

Tags: google-analytics

why is visits 0 in some ga records?

the visiter visit my site , then the visits should be at least 1. but I check my ga reports, there are many reocord has 0 visits. 
and by the way, there are many time values 0 too . any one tells why?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This boils down to the data model used in Google Analytics.

The visit is assigned to the first page but not subsequent pages, whereas unique visitors are assigned to each page. Notice that for each page that has 0 visits, the number of unique visitors is 1 or more. More details [here](http://www.michaelwhitaker.com/blog/2010/04/23/unique-visitors-0-visits-and-pages-in-web-analytics/).